# Integral arithmetic

Tags: integration

Assume we want to calculate the next integral. is it possible to say that:

$$\int_\gamma Pdx+Qdy =\int_\gamma Pdx + \int_\gamma Qdy $$

If not, any idea how to solve this type of integral without using green's therorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the integral of a sum is equal to the sum of the integrals. This is intuitive if you think of integrals as just "a fancy way of adding things up."

Also, if this is a work integral, you add the x- and y-components of the work separately anyways.